# How to apply CSS to JSP file?

Tags: java, css, jsp

i am trying to apply css styling to .jsp file.

I have seperated header and footer. css works to other files but not applying to the file in the folder.

**I have given the folde strucutre down below.**

There is a file inside the **jobs folder**. Css is applying to every jsp page but it is not applying to the page inside **jobs folder**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eorgN.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>AdminLTE 3 | Dashboard</title>

    <%@include file="../header_css_link.jsp" %>
    
</head>

...

<%@include file="../footer_css_link.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```